# jQuery: using select onchange event to fill sibling text field?

Tags: jquery, select

```
<select onchange="$(self).siblings('input[type=text]').val( $(self).val() ); $(self).siblings('input[type=checkbox]').attr('checked','checked')">
```

that does not work

before the select box, there are these inputs (examples):

```
<input type="text" value="" id="product[14][value]" name="product[14][value]">
<input type="checkbox" value="1" id="product[14][enabled]" name="product[14][enabled]">
```

after debugging in firebug, i found that it is in fact finding the siblings, and the part that is failing is filling the text field with the select's value:

```
.val( $(self).val() );
```

what's wrong with it?
thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$(this)`, not `$(self)`.  `self` refers to the window property `window.self` (which is in fact the `window` object.

Comment: It is often used, though, as an alias for `this` inside closures. At least by me.

Comment: @MvanGeest: yes, you see `self` used as *storage* for `this` in a lot of online examples and it's probably what confused the OP.

Comment: Storage... I believe the best explanation is that "`self` will reference the same object that `this` referenced". It's not a value-based action. I agree with your point.